# Output Format for double

Tags: c#, string, tostring

I've simple question on formatting. I've a double returning a number that will always be a multiple of 0.5. (e.i. the number can be 125.5, 125, 160, 171.5)
In my output window I am currently printing something like this:

```
double number;
(number).ToString("###0.0");
```

However, in the case my number is an integer, such as 125, this returns a value of 125.0, which I would like the number to be printed out as 125, whilst keeping the capability of printing out the decimal number in case the double number was for example 126.5.

Does anybody know how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In C# Use `String.Format`

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);                    // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);                       // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);                       // "123.00"

String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);                    // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4);                       // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);                       // "123"

String.Format("{0:00.0}", 123.4567);                    // "123.5"
String.Format("{0:00.0}", 23.4567);                     // "23.5"
String.Format("{0:00.0}", 3.4567);                      // "03.5"
String.Format("{0:00.0}", -3.4567);                     // "-03.5"

String.Format("{0:0,0.0}", 12345.67);                   // "12,345.7"
String.Format("{0:0,0}", 12345.67);                     // "12,346"

String.Format("{0:0.0}", 0.0);                          // "0.0"
String.Format("{0:0.#}", 0.0);                          // "0"
String.Format("{0:#.0}", 0.0);                          // ".0"
String.Format("{0:#.#}", 0.0);                          // ""

String.Format("{0:0.00;minus 0.00;zero}", 123.4567);    // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00;minus 0.00;zero}", -123.4567);   // "minus 123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00;minus 0.00;zero}", 0.0);         // "zero"
```

Comment: Apparently you know what language the OP is using. Perhaps you can edit the question to add the appropriate tag.

Comment: the user asked 2 other questions related to C#. so i'm voting to C#

Answer (score 1):

Try using this format string:

```
"###0.#"
```

I'm assuming from your capitalisation of `ToString` that this relates to C#.